# Passing Selected Row data using EventArgs e

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Can someone help me with my GridView `EventHandler` problem? I have this GridView that has a button for each row that will extract data to excel using the `ID` as filter to my LINQ.

My problem is that how will I do it using the only two parameter present on the method of the `EventHandler`?

```
protected void gvJobs_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "btnExtract_Click")
    {                                                                
         int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
         GridViewRow row = gvJobs.Rows[index];

         //EventHandler call
         ExtractJobsCalibrationForm(sender, e);
    }                                                                
}
```

It triggers the event but I'd like to know if how the data for a specific row button that was click will pass the ID of that selected row to the `EventHandler`.

Here is my code for the `EventHandler`:

```
void View_ExtractJobsCalibrationForm(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
        using (Data.DataContexts.IDataContext objContext = Data.DataContexts.DataContext.CreateDataContext()) 
        {
            IQueryable<Data.JobSummary> objJobs = objContext.Jobs.GetJobSummaries().Where(j => !j.IsDeleted);

            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Reports/ExcelTemplate/Calibration_Form_ARS-FORM-CL1_Template.xlsx");
            string destPath = @"C:\Users\ringgo_dejesus\Desktop\Calibration_Form_ARS-FORM-CL1_Template.xlsx";


            oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

            //Create a copy from the Template to save the data.
            System.IO.File.Copy(path, destPath, true);

            //Open the copied template.
            mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(destPath, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

            //Get all the sheets in the workbook
            mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;
            //Get the allready exists sheet
            mWSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item("Pre calibration Check in");

            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = mWSheet.UsedRange;
            //int colCount = range.Columns.Count;
            //int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;

            //for (int index = 1; index < 15; index++)
            //{
            //    mWSheet.Cells[rowCount + index, 1] = rowCount + index;
            //    mWSheet.Cells[rowCount + index, 2] = "New Item" + index;
            //}

            Excel.Range JobNo = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[2, 2];
            Excel.Range Date = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[3, 2];
            Excel.Range CheckedInBy = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[4, 2];
            Excel.Range ClientName = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[7, 2];
            Excel.Range ClientNum = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[8, 2];
            Excel.Range PONumber = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[9, 2];
            Excel.Range MonitorManufacturer = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[22, 4];
            Excel.Range MonitorModel = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[23, 4];
            Excel.Range MonitorSerialNum = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[24, 4];
            Excel.Range ProbeManufacturer = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[26, 4];
            Excel.Range ProbeModel = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[27, 4];
            Excel.Range ProbeSerialNum = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[28, 4];
            Excel.Range LastCalibrated = (Excel.Range)mWSheet.Rows.Cells[37, 4];

            var data = objJobs.Where(j => j.JobReference.Contains(View.JobReferenceNo.Trim()))
                              .Select(x => new
                              {
                                  JobNum = x.JobReference,
                                  CreationDate = x.DateCreated,
                                  CreatedBy = x.CreatedByUserId,
                                  ClientName = x.ClientName,
                                  ClientNumber = x.ClientId,
                                  PONumber = x.PurchaseOrderNumber
                              }).FirstOrDefault();

            JobNo.Value = data.JobNum;
            Date.Value = data.CreationDate;
            CheckedInBy.Value = data.CreatedBy;
            ClientName.Value = data.ClientName;
            ClientNum.Value = data.ClientNumber;
            PONumber.Value = data.PONumber;

            mWorkBook.Save();
            //mWorkBook.SaveAs(path, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

            //mWorkBook.Close(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            mWSheet = null;
            mWorkBook = null;
            //oXL.Quit();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception objException)
    {
        View.DisplayException(objException);
    }
}
```

And I'd like to use the selected row number or Id to filter my LINQ for `objJobs`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to get the record ID for that selected row.

below code will give you the selectedRow's record ID if it is present in your gridview's design in design page.

To do this use below logic:

```
protected void gvJobs_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "btnExtract_Click")
        {    
             int yourSelectedID = (((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex;     
             //
                  //do stuff with yourSelectedID
             //EventHandler call
             ExtractJobsCalibrationForm(yourSelectedID);
             //  


        }                                                                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the ID you need into gvJobs DataKeyNames attribute, then retrieve the ID for each row as needed.

**.aspx example**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvJobs" runat="server" DataKeyNames="YourIdNameGoesHere" />
```

**.aspx.cs example (within button OnClick event)**

```
Button button = sender as Button;
GridViewRow gridViewRow = button.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvJobs.DataKeys[gridViewRow.RowIndex].Value);
```